# Conditional Behavior with Custom Error Signals

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling

I am working on a .NET project where the team decided to sidestep the convention of Exceptions in favor of a custom error signal.  In practice, the concept works well enough, except there is one nasty side effect: I find myself constantly checking intermediate error codes before deciding whether to proceed:

```
var error = DoSomething();

if( !error.Success )
    return error;

return DoSomethingElse();
```

What I would like to do is something like the following:

```
DoSomething().ReturnIfError();
return DoSomethingElse();
```

I know some languages such as Ruby support the 'return if' construct - is there any such thing in C#, or would it be possible to do so in an extension method?

Comment: are you saying return a Method() to run or the MethodName..?..because var error in your case would return true or false.. if I am reading this correctly.. you want to return a Method to run..?

Comment: if you are wanting to return the MethodName of itself for example.. check out this link it will be able to hopefully give you an Idea as to what to do and how to do it.. assuming that I am understanding your question correctly.. http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/233553-get-function-name

Comment: This example is fairly contrived... the point is I want to continue execution, not just execute a method, if an error has not been detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that can be prettily hacked in with extension methods.

In the second example you gave (with the theoretical method chaining), you would...

- call `DoSomething`
- if `DoSomething` errored out, call `ReturnIfError`
- then call `DoSomethingElse`

You need to use the `return` keyword to break out of a method block early.

Assuming that this is what you really want to do, then the following code can make that happen (not that I recommend it!).

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    public static class ClassUtility
    {
        public static void CallOnError<TIn>(this TIn value, Func<TIn, bool> fn, Action<TIn> errorFn)
            where TIn : class
        {
            if (!fn(value))
            {
                errorFn(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class TestClass
    {
        public bool FirstCall(bool value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First call.");
            return value;
        }

        public void SecondCall()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second call.");
        }

        public void ThirdCall()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Third call.");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testClass = new TestClass();

            testClass.CallOnError(tc => tc.FirstCall(false),
                                  tc2 => tc2.SecondCall());

            testClass.CallOnError(tc => tc.FirstCall(true),
                                  tc2 => tc2.SecondCall());

            testClass.ThirdCall();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid that was the case.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score -1):

Do a single universal class that checks that error and call that class or static method throughout the code.